# Placing support functions into the main

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working through an exercise covering definition functions and I've hit a snag in regards to placing all my support functions into the main.

Here is how the code originally looked..

```
fn = input('Enter filename: ')
f = open(fn)
f.readline()  # Skip the first two lines
f.readline()
line = f.readline()  # Line containing site info
stuff = line.split(',')
print('\nSite: {}.\n(lat, long) = ({}, {})'.format(stuff[0], stuff[3], stuff[4]))

# Now process body of file, accumulating monthly rainfalls.

f.readline()
f.readline()
f.readline()
f.readline()
f.readline()
f.readline()

line = f.readline()
stuff = line.split(',')
rfs = 12 * [0]  # Rainfall totals for months
while len(stuff) > 1:
    date = stuff[1]
    m = int(date[4:6])   # Month
    rainfall = float(stuff[2])
    rfs[m - 1] += rainfall
    line = f.readline()
    stuff = line.split(',')

# Print results

months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
print('\nMonth  Rainfall')
for i in range(12):
    print(' {} {:6.1f}'.format(months[i], rfs[i]))

print('\nTotal rainfall = {:.1f}'.format(sum(rfs)))
f.close()
```

This prints out ..

```
Enter filename:
Site: Christchurch Aero.
(lat, long) = (-43.493, 172.537)

Month  Rainfall
 Jan   58.0
 Feb   35.4
 Mar   54.2
 Apr   50.8
 May   52.6
 Jun   41.0
 Jul   29.4
 Aug   62.6
 Sep   21.4
 Oct   90.8
 Nov   63.6
 Dec   60.8

Total rainfall = 620.6
```

I've tried to split this code now into separate functions but whenever I go to run the code it just freezes and I'm unsure on what the underlying problem is. Here is what I have..

```
def main():
    '''Main function, opens the text file, reads and then prints the
    relevant info'''
    file_input = input('Enter filename: ')
    file = open(file_input)

    file.readline()
    file.readline()

    site_line = file.readline()  # Line containing site info
    site_info = site_line.split(',')
    print('\nSite: {}.\n(lat, long) = ({}, {})'.
          format(site_info[0], site_info[3], site_info[4]))

    rfs = rainfall_function(file)

    print_rainfall(rfs)

def rainfall_function(file):
    '''Read text file for the required data and process the information'''   
    file.readline()
    file.readline()
    file.readline()
    file.readline()
    file.readline()
    file.readline()  

    rain_line = file.readline()
    rain_info = rain_line.split(',')
    rfs = 12 * [0]  # Rainfall totals for months
    while len(rain_info) > 1:
        date = rain_info[1]
        month = int(date[4:6])   # Month
        rainfall = float(rain_info[2])
        rfs[month - 1] += rainfall
    return rfs


def print_rainfall(rfs):
    '''Months to print rainfall statistics for'''
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', ' May', 'Jun', 
              'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    print('\nMonth  Rainfall')

    for i in range(12):
        print(' {} {:6.1f}'.format(months[i], rfs[i]))

    print('\nTotal rainfall = {:.1f}'.format(sum(rfs)))     

main()
```

I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried running your code, but you have an obvious infinite loop:

```
while len(rain_info) > 1:
        date = rain_info[1]
        month = int(date[4:6])   # Month
        rainfall = float(rain_info[2])
        rfs[month - 1] += rainfall
```

This will loop as long as `len(rain_info) > 1` but nothing inside the loop changes the length of `rain_info`.  So, if this loop is ever entered, it will never leave again.

It is often useful to insert `print()` statements to see what your code is doing.  If you had a print before and after this loop, you would see the before print and not see the after.  If you had a print inside the loop you would see it repeating.

It can also be useful to single-step your code.  There are several debuggers available for Python; the one I have used has been the one in the Wingware IDE.  There is a free version for students.

EDIT: Looking at your original code, I see why it didn't have the infinite loop.  It includes these lines:

```
while len(stuff) > 1:
    # ...lines omitted...
    line = f.readline()
    stuff = line.split(',')
```

So each time the loop runs, it tries to read another input line, and then splits the line it gets.  Since the original while loop depends on `len(stuff)`, the loop can terminate as a result of the code inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah, turns out I'd just chopped that part of the code off. Very basic mistake, cheers for pointing it out ><